# <apptags:SQLIteratorTag query="<%=myQuery%>"> where myQuery returns no results results in strange HTML behaviour

Tags: html, sql, jsp, tomcat7

I am using Tomcat7 on Windows Server 2008.

I have the following two lines in my JSP page

```
<apptags:SQLIteratorTag query="<%=myQuery%>">
</apptags:SQLIteratorTag>
```

If `myQuery` returns at least one row, then my JSP page behaves normally.
If `myQuery` returns no rows, then my JSP page copies some text from the page (e.g. the contents of a combobox) and duplicates it!

My thoughts are as follows: Since the combobox that it copies from is populated by a query, it seems that in the absence of a query returning results, the page seems to grab the results of a different query.

Has anyone got any ideas how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: The most likely reason for the query returning no rows is because no company was selected. So I can put a condition around the two lines, `<%if (noCompanySelected) {%>` and `<%}%>` but I would prefer something neater...

Comment: As in the comment above, if I know in advance that the query will not return any rows, then the code in the comment above will provide a workaround. However sometimes I do not know if the query will return results, therefore the only way of solving it would be to write another query which will count the rows of the original query, and if the answer is zero, then employ the above workaround.  However this method is very messy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scriptlets `<%...%>` in a JSP body are oftenly messy. They can be fully avoided by using [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) `@taglib` with [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) `${...}`, which is the clean and highly recommended way to iterate your query results in JSP.

Download [jstl-api.jar and jstl-impl.jar](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/downloads/index.html), put them in your lib folder and add to the top of the page:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
```

For the query part, leave all the processing to a Java class, storing the query results in a variable `myList` of type `List` and sending it (get/post forward) to your page, which should only show the values and nothing else:

```
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="product" varStatus="status">
    Product number ${status.count}: ${product}<br />
</c:forEach>
```

This should be enough to avoid unexpected behaviours in your page. It'll simply do nothing if there's no rows. But if you still wanna check that, you wouldn't have to do the query again, since its results are already inside `myList`:

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(myList) != 0}">
    <c:forEach items="${myList}" var="product" varStatus="status">
        Product number ${status.count}: ${product}<br />
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Or use `${noCompanySelected}` instead of `${fn:length(myList) != 0}`, if that's really your condition.

...Other things you may want to verify:

Your `myQuery` is being reused by something else, somewhere else in your application... or recursively twice by the same page if you created `myQuery` in the session instead of request.

Also, if your taglib `apptags` was made by yourself, another possibility is that it's manipulating tags it shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks very much for answer.  I need to investigate this in the next couple of days...

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer. This will definitely "raise the level" of my JSP code...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your page I would bet that you are using the same variable name as in:

```
%=myQuery%
```

Therefore when no query result is returned it is just returning the last object it had... i.e the combo box. Try giving your query string name a different name like query1, query2, etc instead of all myQuery.

Comment: Hi Shawn. Thank you very much for your answer.  The queries do indeed have different names. I renamed the query in question with a completely unique name "myQuery23812463" just to check, but the problem still persists.